# Calculate the derivative in terms of $\phi$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was trying to verify the machine learning lecture notes given by Andrew ([page 2](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes7b.pdf)). The notation might slightly off if considering in a math perspective.

Known $Z^{(i)}$ ~ Multinomial($\phi$) where $\phi_{j} \geq 0$, $\sum_{j=0}^k \phi_j =1$ and the parameter $\phi_{j}$ gives $p(z^{(i)}=j)$, and $x^{(i)} | z^{(i)} = j$ ~ $\mathcal{N}(\mu_j, \Sigma_j)$. Also, $x^{(i)}$ here is a vector.

Maximize the following function:

$\mathcal{l} (\phi, \mu,\Sigma) = \sum_{i=1}^m \log P(x^{(i)}|z^{(i)};\mu,\Sigma) + \log(z^{(i)};\phi)$

**I am interested in optimal value of $\phi_j$.**

My calculation process:

Keep the first item as it is, since we are not interested at this step. Written in a Lagrangian form:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^m \Big[ \log P(x^{(i)}|z^{(i)};\mu,\Sigma) + \sum_{j=1}^k \log \phi_j^{1\{z^{(i)}=j\}} + \lambda(1-\sum_{j=1}^{k}\phi_j) \Big]
\end{align*}
where $\phi_j \geq 0$ is left on purpose (it won't affect the calculation).

Then,
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}}{\partial \phi} = \sum_{i=1}^m 1\{z^{(i)}=j\} \frac{1}{\phi_j}-\lambda = 0$$
thus
$$\phi_j = \sum_{i=1}^m 1\{z^{(i)}=j\} \frac{1}{\lambda}$$ 
where $\lambda > 0$ according to KKT, and $\lambda$ not necessary equals to $m$.

However the **given solution** is $$\phi_j = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m 1\{z^{(i)}=j\}$$ what did I miss?

**Updates**

I think I've figured it out.

Plug $\phi_j$ into $\sum_{j=1}^{k}\phi_j = 1$, we have

$$\sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{m} 1\{z^{(i)}=j\} \frac{1}{\lambda}= 1$$
that is,
$$\lambda = m$$